# if Request.Form Not Working On Page (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

I am new to ASP.net and have this code on a page:

```
<% IF (Request.Form("clicked")="clicked") %>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.colorbox({
    iframe      : true,
    innerWidth  : 430,
    innerHeight : 208,
    href        : "/v/browse_market.asp"
  });
});
</script>
<%ELSE%>
<%END IF%>
```

Basically I only want the Colorbox to load if the user has come to the page through a form button that was clicked. The form on the previous page is here:

```
<form method="post" action="/clothing_s/1814.htm">
<input type="hidden" name="clicked" value="clicked" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Browse Products" />
</form>
```

There are other ways to get to the page and the Colorbox loads even if I haven't submitted the form. Is my syntax correct? I am very familiar with conditional structures etc. but am mainly a PHP user so am not sure if I got that entirely right (it looks right in relation to examples I've seen that's why I ask).

Comment: Are you doing MVC or WebForms?  I have almost no experience with MVC, but if you're doing WebForms, it looks like there's a whole slew of "how asp.net works" you need to learn before this question is answerable.  Teis looks more like classic ASP than ASP.NET to me.

Comment: I am very new to ASP. All I know is I'm using a Volusion template that's in ASP. I am posting the form and trying to do what would be the equivalent of isset($_POST) in PHP. Maybe you can clarify how web forms differ in ASP? Thanks, sorry if I'm not understanding entirely...

Comment: I think you'll need a `THEN` on the end of your `IF` line. Given the 'href' in your `colorbox` function, this is almost certainly classic ASP, not ASP.NET; you should change the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait wait. Why is your FORM tag looking like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="/clothing_s/1814.htm">
```

The action should be targeted to a valid ASP.Net webpage running under IIS. A valid FORM tag may look something like this if you are running ASP.Net page on your own machine (local).

```
    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:4650/My-ASP.Net-In-IIS/default.aspx">
```

Rest of the code seems fine, it should work.

Having said that, I am not saying that whatever you have written SHOULD be written this way. You wrote ASP.Net in a PHP style, which is not correct. But it must work at least.

I hope this answers your question. If yes, please mark it as "answered".

Comment: No, that's not an escape slash in the link, it's the subdirectory link. The form goes to the correct page (http://www.mysite.com/clothing_s/1814.htm) when I submit it. Would that matter? I'll try it now but wasn't sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: Also, that wouldn't affect the target page. The problem really is that the Colorbox loads even if I just go directly to the target page (instead of clicking through to it).

Comment: How a HTML page `1814.htm` will resolve ASP.Net code tags? Page has to be a valid .aspx page running under IIS.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Yeah that makes sense. Sorry, I'm having to do this through an e-commerce site template that I can't alter so I figured it generated ASP pages (since the site is written that way) every time. Thanks for pointing that out. Let me take a look.

Comment: Let me know if you need further help. Remember to mark my original post as "answered" if that served you. :-)

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to explore it a little more and I will make sure to come back with more questions or to mark your post answered!

Comment: Alright you were definitely on the right track. I just found out that the e-commerce template site I use actually generates an SEO friendly URL even though it's still an ASP file (which you wouldn't have known so your answer makes sense). I can actually edit the ASP through their template, it has to be sent to them and placed into the code which is why it didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out, at last. :-)